# Zend Framework 2 Mod Rewrite in htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

I wrote application using ZF2 and at the end of the project I use some htaccess rewrite rules which let me to remove `public` keyword from application url. I found this rule in a internet tutorial and it works fine but i tried to add my own mappings and they don't work. Here is my .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index [NC,L]
```

I tried to add rule

```
RewriteRule ^test-test-test-test-providers$ /providers?localisation=$2&serviceType=$4 [NC,L]
```

at the last line of file but, after checking, Zend is giving me error that requested URL can't be found in mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in the public dir:

```
RewriteRule ^test-test-test-test-providers$ /public/providers
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your answer. Yes, i tried to add `/public/` to mapping but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you remove the public via htaccess? The prefered solution is to set the main directory of your domain to the public folder, as described at https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/installation.html - there is also a suggestion for a htaccess file. But this is not necessary when the current settings also work.

> Zend is giving me error that requested URL can't be found in mapping
>   This one is important. I assume you mean that the error comes from the Zend Framework (Zend is only a company, it could be also the Zend). That means, that your request goes directly to the Zend Framework. Wouldn't it be better to use your route directly in the route configuration instead of remap it with your htaccess rules?

Could be possible, if the Zend Framework is still using the "test-test-test-test-providers" for it's routing. If so, you should use it in your routing configuration or test a Redirect instead of a RewriteRule; but this means, that the "test-test-test-test-providers" in the URL will be replaced by the "providers".

Comment: Hi av3, your idea is very simple and I will probably do it your way but my goal was to do mapping via htaccess file :)

Comment: Another way doing it via htaccess would be the Redirect (301), but I assume you want to keep "test-test-test-test-providers" in your URL.

The problem could be, that the Router uses the URL and the URL doesn't change after a rewrite. This is the reason why the Router gives you the error that the URL can't be found in your mapping. But I'm not sure; could be helpful to debug and check which URL the Router is really using.